# Mui TabList overflowing when wrapped inside a grid

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-grid

In the code below the tabs are overflowing past the visible width after wrapping in the `TabsWrapper`. I have a use case where the tabs will always be rendered in a similar wrapper. Is it possible to override some styles in `ScrollableTabs` to achieve the default behaviour?

- I'm getting the feeling that there should be a fix as this seems like a common use case w.r.t to CSS Grid and Flex.
- Just in case you aren't familiar with the default behaviour, try rendering `ScrollableTabs` without it being wrapped in the `TabsWrapper`.

```
import React from "react";
import { TabContext, TabPanel, TabList } from "@mui/lab";
import { Box, Tab, Stack } from "@mui/material";

/** Cannot be changed */
function TabsWrapper(props) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "grid", gridAutoFlow: "row" }}>{props.children}</div>
  );
}

/** Cannot be changed */
function MyTabList(props) {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row">
      <TabList
        orientation="horizontal"
        variant="scrollable"
        onChange={props.onChange}
      >
        {props.children}
      </TabList>
    </Stack>
  );
}

/** Can be changed */
export default function ScrollableTabs() {
  const tabValues = [...Array(30)].map((_, index) => String(index + 1));
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState("1");

  const handleChange = (_, newValue) => {
    setTab(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <TabsWrapper>
      <TabContext value={tab}>
        <MyTabList onChange={handleChange}>
          {tabValues.map((value) => (
            <Tab label={`Tab ${value}`} value={value} key={value} />
          ))}
        </MyTabList>
        <Box>
          {tabValues.map((value) => (
            <TabPanel value={value} key={value}>
              Tab content {value}
            </TabPanel>
          ))}
        </Box>
      </TabContext>
    </TabsWrapper>
  );
}
```

- Working codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-custom-scrollable-tabs-2mfcjr

Thanks!

Comment: Why `MyTabList` and `TabsWrapper` can't be changed?

Comment: It's just the way it's implemented in my case, however I could target `MyTabList` styles using the [styled API](https://mui.com/system/styled/), but cannot do anything with `TabsWrapper`.

Comment: Your problem seems to be a conflict between the styles of `TabsWrapper` and `Stack`, if you remove the style from TabsWrapper's div, you will see that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping `TabContext` in `<div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>` fixes the issue.

The `ScrollableTabs` jsx should look like -

```
export default function ScrollableTabs() {
  const tabValues = [...Array(30)].map((_, index) => String(index + 1));
  const [tab, setTab] = React.useState("1");

  const handleChange = (_, newValue) => {
    setTab(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <TabsWrapper>
      <div style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}>
        <TabContext value={tab}>
          <MyTabList onChange={handleChange}>
            {tabValues.map((value) => (
              <Tab label={`Tab ${value}`} value={value} key={value} />
            ))}
          </MyTabList>
          <Box>
            {tabValues.map((value) => (
              <TabPanel value={value} key={value}>
                Tab content {value}
              </TabPanel>
            ))}
          </Box>
        </TabContext>
      </div>
    </TabsWrapper>
  );
}
```

- Working codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-custom-scrollable-tabs-forked-6ycqfv